# CPU parameter in the task is not behaving as a hard limit and is not setting either cpu-quota or cpuset on docker

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

#### Description

CPU limits in Amazon ECS can be configured at two levels: task level and container level. The task-level setting is intended to enforce a hard limit and is implemented using `--cpu-quota`, as indicated in this resolved issue [GitHub Issue #1093](https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-agent/issues/1093).

However, when deploying a container and only setting the CPU limit at the task level, it does not seem to impact any CPU hard limit options when inspecting the container using docker inspect.

For example, the task definition specifies a CPU limit at the container level as 0 and at the task level as 262, supposedly representing a hard limit:

```
{
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "name": "nginx",
            "image": "nginx:stable-alpine3.17-slim",
            "cpu": 0,
            "memory": 524,
            "memoryReservation": 524,
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "name": "nginx-80-tcp",
                    "containerPort": 80,
                    "hostPort": 0,
                    "protocol": "tcp",
                    "appProtocol": "http"
                }
            ],
            "essential": true
        }
    ],
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "compatibilities": [
        "EC2"
    ],
    "requiresCompatibilities": [
        "EC2"
    ],
    "cpu": "262",
    "memory": "524",
    "runtimePlatform": {
        "cpuArchitecture": "X86_64",
        "operatingSystemFamily": "LINUX"
    }
}
```

#### Expected Behavior

When running `docker inspect <container_id> | grep -i cpu` expect to change `NanoCpus`, `CpusetCpus` or `CpuQuota` to implement a hard limit.

#### Observed Behavior

```
"CpuShares": 2,
"NanoCpus": 0,
"CpuPeriod": 0,
"CpuQuota": 0,
"CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
"CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
"CpusetCpus": "",
"CpusetMems": "",
"CpuCount": 0,
"CpuPercent": 0
```

#### Environment Details

`Amazon ECS Agent - v1.70.0 Docker version 20.10.17, build 100c701`